Undefined symbols: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode Build error
Now I got errors that is
'Undefined symbols:
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode Build error'.

ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftXPC': library 'swiftXPC' not found
ld: Undefined symbols:
_swift_FORCE_LOAD$_swiftXPC, referenced from:
_swift_FORCE_LOAD$swiftXPC$_KakaoSDKCertCore in KakaoSDKCertCore3
_swift_FORCE_LOAD$swiftXPC$_KakaoSDKFriendCore in KakaoSDKFriendCore3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I've also completely deleted and reinstalled pods before.
If you try again from a backed up project, the same problem occurs.
I need help.
I've also completely deleted and reinstalled pods before.
I tried partially installing the pod item, but it didn't work.
I also tried a clean build.
If you try again from a backed up project, the same problem occurs.

Can you switch to use SPM?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Linker error because it could not read some missing symbols. This could happen due to several reasons:

Missing frameworks or files: Go to Build Phase to make sure appropriate frameworks/libraries are linked. Make sure appropriate frameworks/libraries are listed under target build settings.

Make sure if you have appropriate Objective-C header files in the bridging header file.

Check Other Linker Flags under build settings.


